# Skiasharp scale bitmap before drawing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I am using a TextToBitmap function, so I can modify the bitmap. But the resolution of the text gets bad when I scale it to a bigger bitmap. To solve that, I set the TextSize to 400, so the text is drawn very big with high resolution which gives me a high resolution bitmap.
The problem is that when the bitmap gets drawn, it is still very big, so I want to scale the bitmap to a specific Height.

Now I know how I can do this, I need to do this:

```
bitmapCollection.Add(bitmapCollection.Count, new TouchManipulationBitmap(TextBitmap)
{
    Matrix = SKMatrix.MakeTranslation(position.X, position.Y),
    Matrix = SKMatrix.MakeScale((float)0.3, (float)0.3),
});
```

But I can't use Matrix 2 times. The translation and scale are neccesary, so how can I modify both?

**EDIT:**

I tried using this:

```
SKMatrix matrix;
bitmapCollection.Add(bitmapCollection.Count, new TouchManipulationBitmap(TextBitmap)
{
    Matrix = SKMatrix.Concat(matrix, SKMatrix.MakeTranslation(position.X, position.Y),
                        SKMatrix.MakeScale((float)0.3, (float)0.3))
});
```

But that gives me the following errors:

> Argument 1 Must be passed with the 'ref' keyword
>   Use of unassigned local variable 'matrix'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [Concat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skmatrix.concat?view=skiasharp-1.68.1#SkiaSharp_SKMatrix_Concat_SkiaSharp_SKMatrix__SkiaSharp_SKMatrix_SkiaSharp_SKMatrix_) to combine two Matrices

```
public static void Concat (ref SkiaSharp.SKMatrix target, ref SkiaSharp.SKMatrix first, ref SkiaSharp.SKMatrix second);
```

There is a lengthy discussion on this topic in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/transforms/matrix).

in your specific case

```
SKMatrix matrix = new SKMatrix();

// matrix will contain the combined value
SKMatrix.Concat(ref matrix, 
  SKMatrix.MakeTranslation(position.X, position.Y),
  SKMatrix.MakeScale((float)0.3, (float)0.3))
```

Comment: I added an example, but please note that both the errors you have are basic C# errors that are pretty clearly explained by the error messages.  You could have easily looked them up, or read through the documentation I linked to for more examples